# Can anybody help me identify this SMD component?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification, surface-mount, short-circuit

I'm trying to identify this SMD component. If I'm not mistaken, what's written there is "23F"

Device: Laptop

Model: Toshiba Satellite C850-P5010

SMD Location: Near display connector

Problem: White screen

Can you help me identify it?

[image]

Comment: it's probably a transistor, but it's probably pretty hard/impossible to tell you exactly which one - 23F is not very detailed as markings go

Comment: Look around on the board, chances are it’s used elsewhere too since single lines on the BOM tends to be replaced by something else to satisfy the bean counters.

Comment: Are you sure it's 23F and not 23P? Hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: @nanash1 , No I'm not sure. Just guessed. The component had a short so it's hard to read what's written. Btw thanks to others for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markings could match with a [Diodes Inc DMP2305U](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Diodes-Incorporated-DMP2305U-7_C2917599.pdf) if the actual marking code is "23P" which, I think, is plausible from the picture. The style of the markings looks like Diodes Inc to me with the rotated date code (barely visible in the picture), but they don't have a part with a "23F" code as far as I can tell, only "23P" and "23X"

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/old-batch_Diodes-Incorporated-DMP2305U-7_C2917599.html))

[image]

Comment: I think so. Thanks for the effort anyway